# How to comment within a render <div>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I've marked a comment with `//` in a React+Webpack project, but the line which was commented out gets rendered in the HTML anyway. I couldn't sworn I've done this before without this unintended side effect. I can't remember anything I changed in my setup that could've caused this. Thoughts?

```
    import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/lib/app-bar';
import NavigationClose from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/navigation/close';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/lib/icon-button';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/lib/menus/menu-item';
import IconMenu from 'material-ui/lib/menus/icon-menu';
import MoreVert from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/navigation/more-vert';




export default class Header extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <div>
// <h2>This is header</h2>
      <AppBar
        title="Elite Global"
        //iconElementLeft={<IconButton><NavigationClose /></IconButton>}
        iconElementRight={
          <IconMenu iconButtonElement={
              <IconButton><MoreVert /></IconButton>
            }>
            <MenuItem primaryText="Refresh" />
            <MenuItem primaryText="Help" />
            <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" />
          </IconMenu>
        } />
      </div>
    }
  }



import React from 'react';
import Header from './header.jsx';


export default () => {
  return <div>
<Header />
  </div>
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can comment like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        //<div>stuff</div>
      }

      {/*<div>stuff</div>*/}
    </div>
  );
}
```